# Is there any reason to hang out with people?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Throughout the game, you are able to call people and ask them to "Hang Out". You can then take them out to either a bar, movies, stripclub, etc.

I know in Grand Theft Auto 4, there were perks given to the player that completely developed a friendship with someone.

Is there any reason to "hang out" with people in Grand Theft Auto 5?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know, this has been (together with the romance part) removed from the game.
Hanging out with your friends is just a way to do the 'pastime activities' which also count towards your 100% checklist. But they can also be done alone. 
And it's a way to get some more back-story through the dialogue.

(Of course you standard perks train while hanging out, e.g. stamina when running, etc.)

Comment: +1 for `it's a way to get some more back-story through the dialogue` That's exactly the reason why I play those. For example when Trevor re-appeared in Michael's life, it became clear that he was familiar with his children. Hanging out with Jimmy taught me how far their connection was, and actually made the game experience deeper for me.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Chaos_99](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131820/6738) has stated, hanging out with friends can help count towards your 100% checklist.

It's also required for the [Three Man Army](http://www.trueachievements.com/a195111/three-man-army-achievement.htm) achievement where you must hang out with both of the other 2 characters and attain a 3 star wanted level for 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you hang out with someone who has a gun and get wanted while hanging out, they will help you fight the cops.

Comment: There's an achievement associated with this: **Three Man Army**. "Survive 3 minutes on at least a 3 star Wanted Level with all three characters together off mission"